# "Could not load file or assembly" error for System.Net.Http

Tags: c#

I'm working on a WinForms application which is being targetted at .Net 4.7.2. When I run the application on my development machine (either by firing up the compiled EXE itself or in debug mode in Visual Studio) it works fine. When I copy the EXE to the machine where I intend it to be run from, I keep getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My development machine is Server 2012R2 (Visual Studio 2019 Community) and the target machine is Server 2016, but both have the latest version of .Net installed. I've tried searching for an answer for almost two days straight but can't find anything concrete. The usual suggestions I've seen are to add binding redirects to the config file, but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

Just wondering anyone else has ever experienced anything like this, and if so, did you ever find a way around it? It's driving me mad!

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the nuget package System.Net.Http added to the project?

Comment: If the build and the deploy machines do not have the same version of Net you cannot just copy the exe file (at least the first time).  You must publish and run the setup.exe to install software which will up[date the dlls on deploy machine to be compatible with the build machine.  Once you do a publish once if you are not adding libraries you can then copy the exe.

Comment: @YStroli It is, and its set to copy local, but when the project is built, the DLL is missing from the bin\Debug folder.